# Convert Postgres JSONB array to comma separated list in a single column

Tags: json, postgresql, aggregate-functions, jsonb

I have JSONB casted column in table that I'd like to represent as a comma separated list in a single column. I've tried a million different approaches and am coming up short. I can't find anything in the Postgres docs that addresses this particular situation, so hoping for some help!

The table in question looks a little like this:

```
date       | order_id | sales_reps
2019-12-01 | 1234     | [{"id": 100, "user": "Jane Doe"}, {"id": 101, "user": "John Doe"}]
```

I'd like to render it as:

```
date       | order_id | sales_reps
2019-12-01 | 1234     | Jane Doe, John Doe
```

I'm able to get relatively close with:

```
select
    date,
    order_id, 
    (select jsonb_agg(t -> 'user') from jsonb_array_elements(sales_reps::jsonb) as x(t)) as sales_reps
from table
```

```
date       | order_id | sales_reps
2019-12-01 | 1234     | ["Jane Doe", "John Doe"]
```

But for the life of me I can't seem to get the output I want - have tried a ton of aggregators and jsonb functions to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `->>` operator to get json values as text and the `string_agg()` aggregate:

```
select
    date,
    order_id,
    (
        select string_agg(t->>'user', ',') 
        from jsonb_array_elements(sales_reps::jsonb) as x(t)
    ) as sales_reps
from my_table
```

[Db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=426f415409f106cdebadeec61924adbb)