# Postgresql JSONB Query Aggregation

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

Trying to figure out an aggregation result for a JsonB Column with the following data

```
part          | data
-----------------------------------
PART1         |[{"type":"box","reference": "box1"},{"type": "dispatch","reference": 
                "d1"},{"type": "dispatch","reference": "d2"}]
```

Need to write a query that can extract an aggregation result for only type = dispatch
The expected result from the query is

```
part          | data
-----------------------------------
PART1         |d1,d2
```

Found a few examples across for these executions but none of them apply to a JSONB with an array, most of them are able to work with objects and even when filter is is not needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a JSON path query to return those values as a JSON array:

```
select part, 
       jsonb_path_query_array(data, '$[*] ? (@.type == "dispatch").reference')
from the_table
```

Converting that into a comma separated list will be a bit cumbersome though.

Comment: Thank you, this got me thinking in the right direction. While this works in extracting the result as an array, but converting to a comma separated output was a challenge.

Answer (score 0):

Finally Found a Solution for the problem with the following query

```
select part,(select string_agg(t->>'reference',',') from jsonb_array_elements(data::jsonb) as x(t) where t->>'type' ='dispatch') as output
```

The [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59290405/convert-postgres-jsonb-array-to-comma-separated-list-in-a-single-column) was of help in arriving at the solution